# Error when using dtruncnorm: Argument 's_x' is not a real vector

Tags: r, statistics

I am attempting to fit a truncated normal distribution to a dataset of 5000 claim sizes using maximum likelihood:

```
l1 = function(theta)
{
  -sum(dtruncnorm(x=size, a=0, b=Inf, mean = theta[1], sd=theta[2]))
}
mle1=optim(par=c(4,4), fn=l1)
```

When I run the `optim(par=c(4, 2), fn=l1)` line however, I get the error:

```
Error in dtruncnorm(x = size, a = 0, b = Inf, mean = theta[1], sd = theta[2]) : 
Argument 's_x' is not a real vector.
```

I know it has something to do with the `size` variable but as far as I can tell it is a vector of integers since when I run `typeof(size)` I get `"integer"` as the output.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the function does not accept sequences. This worked for me:

```
-sum(sapply(size, function(v){
 dtruncnorm(x=as.numeric(v), a=0, b=Inf, mean = theta[1], sd=theta[2])
}))
```